# Rails Active Record join query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

help my with next question:

I have table `brands` and table `products` ( `has_many - belongs_to association` )

in table products i have field "`Rank`".

And i want to display top5 brands whose total rank of its products - greatest

I try to:

```
Brand.joins(:products).order('products.rank DESC').limit(10).uniq!
```

But that incorrect - thats not a sum of products.rank...

**How to relize with sum of product ranks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, but you missed out on grouping and performing the sum on the grouped objects:

```
Brand.joins(:products).group("brands.id").order('SUM(products.rank) DESC').limit(5)
```

Comment: ERROR:  column reference "id" is ambiguous // with SQL =>              SELECT  "brands".* FROM "brands" INNER JOIN "products" ON "products"."brand_id" = "brands"."id" GROUP BY id(this id) ORDER BY SUM(products.rank) DESC

Comment: Thanks, it's my fault. my mistake =)